# How to delete a hive database with spark-sql?

Tags: database, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

In my use-case I want to "create or replace" a hive database from spark-sql. I was wondering whether that is even possible? or do I have to manually delete all tables within the database in a for-loop first and then drop the empty database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with below

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS <database_name> CASCADE;
```

- **`CASCADE`** will drop all the tables in the database.
- Default, the mode is **`RESTRICT`** hive will not delete database if there are some tables exists in the db.

Once you drop the database then **`create a new database`** using spark-sql.

For more info refer to [Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/Alter/UseDatabase) page.

---

Next option would be the way you have suggested in the post (**`delete all tables then drop the database`**)

Comment: thank you for your answer. but this is sql for hive. does this work within spark-sql too?

Comment: Yes, it works for me (using CDH-5.14 + spark-1.6 + hive-1.1)..!!

Comment: How can I delete all the tables of the default database? spark.sql("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS default CASCADE") AnalysisException: 'Can not drop default database;'

Answer (score 2):

In order to **delete the database and all the tables**:

```
spark_session.sql(f'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {db_name} CASCADE')
```

---

In order to **delete a specific table**:

```
spark_session.sql(f'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {db_name}.{table_name}')
```